# Preload a library on a system with musl libc

Tags: linux

On glibc systems, when I want to preload a library (for example, hardened_malloc) I would do:

`echo /usr/lib/libhardened_malloc > /etc/ld.so.preload`

But musl doesn't support it.

Anyone know how to preload a library globally on musl? I don't want to use LD_PRELOAD for every single binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The musl libc
[Environment Variables](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/environment-variables.html)
article includes this useful variable:

> **LD_PRELOAD**
>
> Colon-separated list of shared libraries that will be preloaded by the
> dynamic linker before processing the application’s dependency list.
> Components can be absolute or relative pathnames or filenames in the
> default library search path.
>
> This variable is completely ignored in programs invoked setuid,
> setgid, or with other elevated capabilities.

---

To make Environment variables persistent you need to define those variables in one of the following configuration files:

- `/etc/environment` : Used to set up system-wide
  environment variables, example:
  `FOO=bar`
- `/etc/profile` : Loaded whenever a bash login shell is entered,
  example:
  `export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/java/home"`
- `~/.bashrc` : Per-user shell specific configuration files,
  example:
  `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: It can be used when launching a specific program, but I want to automatically use it for any program, globally.

Comment: You may define the variable globally.

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: I added more information to my answer.